# How to create Dict from Collection Property in Blender python?

Tags: python, add-on

I want to get a dict from a collection property which will be used for exporting a json file.
I completely have no idea how I should do it, so I don't have any code for it.

Thanks for helping me.

I have a propertyGroup-

```
class Favourites(PropertyGroup):
    label: StringProperty(
        name="Label",
        default="",
    )
    idname: StringProperty(
        name="idname",
        default="",
    )
    icon_value: IntProperty(
        name="Icon value",
        default=0,
    )
    index: IntProperty(
        name='index',
        default=0
    )
    is_preset: BoolProperty(
        name='Is preset',
        default=False
    )
    mode: StringProperty()
```

And this property group is registered as Type of a CollectionProperty in `register` def

```
bpy.types.Scene.favit = CollectionProperty(type=Favourites)
```

I want the list of data in `bpy.context.scene.favit`  to be stored in a json.

Comment: `dict(your_collection)`? Recommend add your data structure to the question, also how you'd like to format your data...

Comment: Hi I added some codes from my script. Please check it.

Comment: Have you tried `dict(C.scene.favit)`?

Comment: `{'': <bpy_struct, Favourites("") at 0x000001A6DB344EC8>}`  It gives this result.  When I try `dict(C.scene.favit[0])` it gives me the properties `{'label': 'Tweak', 'idname': 'builtin.select', 'icon_value': 986, 'index': 0, 'is_preset': 0}
`  I have a list of those properties per fav

Comment: looks like a dict :) What else?

Comment: Did you except to keep default value?

Comment: @brockmann I am finding hard to explain, my English not good. I want to save the favourites to a json file. The favourites are in `C.scene.favit`. if I dict(C.scene.favit[0]) a single item it gives me its properties. How do I save the whole list of favourites  with properties? Please pardon my explanation.

Comment: @HikariTW I don't know if I understood your question.  When I add a new favourite, all default values are overwritten.

Comment: @MeBMan That's good, since if you don't overwrite them, they won't exist in the first  place when Blender initial it.

Comment: No worries, just trying to figure out what you'd like to achieve @MeBMan Final question: How the json string should look like?

Comment: @brockmann Thanks so much for giving your time!, HikariTW gave a solution which is working for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to write out default value, just use `items()` like dictionary.

Unless you assign it, Blender will not create an entry for them.

```
import bpy
import json

data = [
    prop.items()
    for prop in bpy.context.scene.favit
]

print(json.dumps(data))  # save this string to json file
```

output:

```
[[["index", 1], ["label", "hello world"]], [["label", "cool world"]]]
```

The output format is same as [key, value] in a list,
once you want to write back to blender,

```
json_string = '''[[["index", 1], ["label", "hello world"]], [["label", "cool world"]]]'''
data = json.loads(json_string)
for prop_list in data:
    prop = bpy.context.scene.favit.add()
    for key, value in prop_list:
        prop[key] = value
```

Comment: What is prop? I get error `NameError: name 'props' is not defined`

Comment: props? I didn't write `props`, `prop` maybe?

Comment: Oh my bad, I did a mistake. it should be ""prop"" not  "props"

Comment: Hi, I think this is what I want. If you could also parse it out, it would be really great, How do I read per favourite when I read from the saved json? Thank you  so much

Comment: Nice Thanks so much!. Working like charm!